# using javascipt to change the size of a font inside the text editor

Tags: javascript, html

I have to create in an application some content through a text editor but that editor does not have an option to change the font size.

However, the text editor allows the HTML code to insert in there.

I want to do that using JS but I'm stuck on how to find the proper way to do it.

My question is how to increase the `font size of all the text inside the p` element?

This is the piece of `html` that is already inside the text editor.

[This is how the generated HTML looks in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3IoX.png)

```js
//this is what i tried but didn't work
document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].style["font-size"] = "20px"
```

```html
<p></p>
<h5><b><span><span><span><i>-8 minutes</i></span></span><span>&nbsp;read</span></span></b></h5>
<p></p>
<p>Here we will see some of the examples.<br><br></p>
<h4><b>Example 1:</b></h4>
<p></p>
```

Comment: We have no idea how your “text editor” works. You need to provide a proper [mre] of issues like this.

Comment: Will it help to add a CSS rule like `p { font-size: 20px }` via JavaScript? Because there are existing solutions for that.

Comment: if you want all <p> tag then used document.queryselectorall("p")

Comment: @CBroe isn't that the code in the question is a `minimal reproducible example`?

Comment: I don’t see any editor functionality in that example. Or are you saying, that is not the important part, and you are basically just asking how to set the font size for a bunch of HTML elements output on a page?

Comment: I don't have any access to the functionality of the editor. I can only have access to HTML inside the text editor, so I posted the HTML which I have access and I can modify. I think that is the only thing that is needed to be modified for this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enlarge all paragraphs, you can do the following.

Things to note include:

1. The `script` element comes **after** the other HTML (usu. inside the `body` element.)
2. The `getElementsByTagName` selector returns all elements of the type `p`.
3. The `for...of` syntax lets us loop through the paragraphs.
4. The `font-size` attribute is represented as the `fontSize` property.

```html
<p></p>
<h5><b><span><span><span><i>-8 minutes</i></span></span><span>&nbsp;read</span></span></b></h5>
<p></p>
<p>Here we will see some of the examples.<br><br></p>
<h4><b>Example 1:</b></h4>
<p></p>
<script>
  let paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName("p");
  for (let p of paragraphs) {
    p.style.fontSize = "20px";
  }
</script>
```

BTW, a better practice would be to set a class instead of changing the style property directly, like:

```
p.classList.add("my-big-class");
```

And in your CSS (which can be in a `style` element inside the `head` element of your HTML), you define the behavior for the class, like:

```
.my-big-class{ font-size: 20px; } /* CSS syntax is a bit different */
```

Comment: but there could be a lot of `p` tag, adding a class in all of the element a better option?

Comment: If you're sure you'll want to select all `p` elements, you can actually just use `p{ font-size: 20px; }` and skip the class thing. (I usually go with a class just to remind myself that there's a style applied to the element, but classes are definitely not the only way to select a group of HTML elements! Use whatever CSS selector is most convenient for you.)

Comment: I would definitely do that but what I observed in my case is when I am using the CSS in that text editor, with `<style></style>` the server sanitized the code and removed everything. so couldn't use the `<style>`

Comment: Selecting by element type is a perfectly valid way to handle styling. It just depends on how the rest of the code looks -- and on personal preference. Btw, if you like the answer, consider marking it as 'accepted'.